# Return value from a promise in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, promise

I am a little bit confused with Promises. I have the following provider in Ionic + Angular:

```
@Injectable()
export class StorageProvider { 

  constructor( public storage:Storage ) {}

  save(keyname: string, data: any): Promise<any> {
    return this.storage.set(keyname, data);
  }

  retrieve(keyname: string): Promise<any> {
    return this.storage.get(keyname);
  }

  clear(): Promise<void> {
    return this.storage.clear();
  }

  delete(keyname): Promise<any> {
    return this.storage.remove(keyname);
  }

  isLogged() {
      return this.retrieve('user').then( value => { value ? true : false });
  }

}
```

And in one of my components:

```
console.log(this.storage.isLogged());
```

The problem is that it returns the promise object and not `true` or `false`

If I change my component to:

```
this.storage.isLogged().then(function(data) { console.log(data)});
```

Then I get an output of `undefined`

Comment: As long as `isLogged` return Promise - `this.storage.isLogged().then(console.log)`

Comment: `isLogged() { return this.retrieve('user').then(value => !!value); }`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Logging promise using `console.log` will just return promise object. `StorageProvider`'s `isLogged` method should have return `true/false` so that the underlying caller will receive value inside `.then` success callback.

```
isLogged() {
  return this.retrieve('user').then( value => { 
    //this return will `return` value in chained manner
     return value ? true : false; 
  });
}
```

Caller

```
this.storage.isLogged().then(
  (value) => console.log("isLogged", value)
)
```

---

## Why inner return statement solved the problem?

Promise is way to deal async request, and it basically has 3 function that can appear in `.then`.

```
myPromiseCall().then(successFn, errorFn, notifyFn)
```

Sweet properties of promise is they can easily chained up. So that interdependent async code looks more readable. So whenever there is case of passing a data of one promise to another, so that time you returns a data from `promiseA` success That will automatically available in `promiseB` success, for eg. below

```
promiseA(){return promise };
promiseB(){ return promise };

promiseA().then( 
   //success fn
   (data) => { 
      //do something
      return data;
   }
).then(
   //success fn
   (promiseAData) => {
      console.log("Promise A data", promiseAData);
      //do some awesome thing based on data retrieved from promiseA

      return promiseB();
   }
).then(successFn, errorFn)
```

It was important task to return a data from `promiseA`, that is how when you returned a data, the underlying chained promise success callback function got that data. If suppose the `promiseA` function didn't returned anything from its success function, the chained `promiseB` would get `undefined`. The similar thing was happening with you.

Comment: I think this is the same with my alternative component and it returns undefined.

Comment: @Tasos please check `isLogged` method in answer.. it should `return value ? true : false; ` from `.then`

Comment: Indeed. The second return inside `then` made the trick. I will choose your answer as the right one, but I would appreciate if you could also explain why I had that behavior and how the second return solved it.

Comment: @Tasos So you want to know why it is necessary to say `return` in order to return something from a function?

Comment: @Tasos please check updated answer, I could not minimize the explanation, please let me know if you don't understand anything..

Comment: But `isLogged()` returns `Promise<boolean>`, not `boolean`. What if I want to return a plain `boolean` from the method? How to do that?

Comment: just `return true` that's it. Do you face any issue while doing that?