# Return an API response from a Promise.then() in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-boot

I'm new in AngularJS and wanted to write a function in AngularJS, which tries to delete a user. On success it should return a boolean, which determines if he was succesfully deleted.

Anyway, the extracted result out of the promise always returns true, even if the Api-Response is false. I tried extracting the response as written here: [Return value from a promise in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45649750/return-value-from-a-promise-in-angular). I also tried other links, but none of them really helped me solving my problem.

user.controller.js:

```
deleteUser(user) {

    const self = this;

    self.userActionPromise = self.userService.deleteUser(user.id).then(deleted => {
        if (deleted) {
            self.messagesService.successMessage('user.DELETE_SUCCESS');
            self.loadUsers();
        } else {
            self.messagesService.errorMessage('user.DELETE_FAILURE');
        }
    });
}
```

user.rest.service.js:

```
self.user = $resource(config.restServerUrl + 'users/:id', {id: '@id'}, {
    delete: {method: 'DELETE'}
});

deleteUser(id) {
    return this.user.delete({id: id}).$promise.then(deleted => {
        return !!deleted;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

result of

```
return this.user.delete({id: id}).$promise.then(deleted => {
  return !!deleted;
})
```

always return true when request finished.

If you want to cover fail result:

```
return this.user.delete({id: id}).$promise.then(deleted => {
  return deleted;
}, function (error) {
  return error;
})
```

second function will be executed when server return an error 
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-error-page

Http responce statusCode should say that came an error, like 500 (https://developer.yahoo.com/social/rest_api_guide/http-response-codes.html).
When you return status code 200, and result `false`, it just say to angularjs that request finished successfuly and result of it `false`

Comment: But is there a way, to return the API-Response (true or false)? The backend won't throw an error, because it checks if the user can be deleted or not. If he can be deleted it returns true and deletes the user, if not it just returns false. And i need to get exactly this result.

Comment: As per my understanding of API, when UI request to delete user but user not deleted, API should return an error

Comment: https://developer.yahoo.com/social/rest_api_guide/http-response-codes.html

for DELETE Operation answers can be '400 Bad Request', '403 Forbidden', '404 Not Found', etc

Comment: After doing some further research, i found out, that DELETE can't give back a boolean like i want it. So your way seems to be the only possible way. I'll mark the answer as the correct one.