# Angular 9 the response value of a promise inside another method is undefined but from the promise method it can be consoled clearly

Tags: angular, promise

I am having the following function that contain a promise:

```
async checkValueIfExists(searchKey, appendedUrl, keyValue, ou, program) {
  const checkValuePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.api.getData(this.globalVar.basicSearchFieldUrl + appendedUrl, 'dhis').subscribe(
      (resp) => {
        resolve(resp);
        // return resp;
      },
      (error) => {
        reject();
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  });
}
```

And here I tried to catch the reponse:

```
async uploadData() {
    let awaitCheckValue =  await this.checkValueInDhis2(searchValue, appendToUrlEqual, keyField, ou, programId).then((res) => {
    console.log(res)
  }).catch(res=>console.log(res));
}
```

The consoled value is always undefined, but when I console it at the function of `checkValueIfExists()` the response appeared.

I tried some solution on stack [overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45649750/return-value-from-a-promise-in-angular) but still the same.

Here is a simplified [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/simplified-promise-jfixc6) about the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because you are resolving something from promise but never returning anything from your async function.

You will need to replace this.

```
const checkValuePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
```

to

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
```

This will work and I have tested on your stackblitz.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/simplified-promise-vj7d1q?file=src/app/app.component.ts